# Elixir : IO.read exit from the terminal

Tags: elixir

I am trying to read inputs using IO.read(:stdio, :all) line by line and I am able to input in the terminal but not able to exit after providing the inputs.

```
defmodule SumOfTwo do
  def main() do
    IO.read(:stdio, :all)
    |> String.split()
    |> Enum.reduce(fn x, acc -> String.to_integer(acc) + String.to_integer(x) end)
    |> IO.puts()
  end
end
```

SumOfTwo.main()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give `:all` to `IO.read/2`, it will read until it gets and `EOF` (end-of-file) character. One is included if you pipe into your elixir script:

```sh
$ echo "2 3 4" | elixir main.exs
9
```

You can also send the EOF character from the terminal. With Linux terminals this is often `ctrl+d`:

```sh
$ elixir main.es
4
5
6
<ctrl+d here>15
```

You'll want to change your reduce function, though, because calling `String.to_integer/1` on on integer is going to raise an error. And my example will let `IO.read/2` default to `:stdio`.

```rb
defmodule SumOfTwo do
  def main() do
    :all
    |> IO.read()
    |> String.split()
    |> Enum.reduce(fn x, acc -> acc + String.to_integer(x) end)
    |> IO.puts()
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually as mentioned in the document if it finds empty string it will treat as an : EOF but from the terminal, it was not detecting that. Anyhow CTRL+d worked.